# detect mobile device and redirect according to screen height using only one index.php file

Tags: php, javascript, mobile

After detecting if my web site is used on a mobile device of not by parsing the USER_AGENT string, 
I would like to redirect the user to the pages optimized for resolutions with height >= 1024 (for example 9.7", 10.1" tablets)
or redirect the user to pages optimized for resolutions < 1024 (for example smarphones and 5", 7", 8" tablets)

To acheive this I need to get the screen resolution with javascript.

We know that PHP (the USER_AGENT parser script) is executed before javascript but I need to get the screen resolution before the parser. 
As I know that a web server executes firstly INDEX.HTML and then INDEX.PHP I wrote a Index.html file which gets the screen width and pass it via a form with POST (to keep the address bar clean rather than $_GET) to Index.php which then loads (includes) the corrects web page.

INDEX.HTML

```
<body onload="document.form.submit();">
    <form name="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" id="height" name="height" value="" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('height').value = screen.height;
    </script>
</body>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
     $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
     // If it's a mobile device...
    if(preg_match(...) {
        // If the device screen height is => 1024 it's a tablet 8", 9.7" or 10.1"
        if ($_POST['height'] >= 1024) {
            include ('include.tablet.php');
        }
        // If the device screen height is < 1024 it's a smartphone or a tablet 5" o 7")...
        else {
            include ('include.smartphone.php');
        }
    }
    // If it's a desktop PC...
    else {
            include ('include.index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing without the HTML file. I wrote a index.php file which gets screen.width and send it to itself with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] 
so that the PHP code may redirect the user to the correct page.

```
<body onload="document.form.submit();">
    <form name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="height" name="height" value="" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('height').value = screen.height;
    </script>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['height'])) {
                // conditional include
    } ?>
</body>
```

The issue is that the method works, but the browser (Firefox) take 1 or 2 seconds to run the page and return the result. Why?

**NO JAVASCRIPT, NO JQUERY:**
I know that I could use a javascript parser and then redirect to the correct page with: 'window.location.href' but **I want my homepage to be always 'index.php'** and not start with index.php which redirects to *tablet.php* or *smartphone.php*. I'm trying to keep the code elegant.

Any suggestion?

Comment: read comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for variable so you don't load JS again:

```
<body>
    <form name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="height" name="height" value="" />
    </form>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['height'])) { 
        echo $_POST['height']; 
     } else { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('height').value = screen.height;
        document.form.submit();
       </script>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</body>
```

---

Alternates:

Could you try using javascript and jQuery in your file like this?

```
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script&gt;

<!-- execute it when the document is ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     if($(window).height() > 1024){
             window.location = "http://pc.yoursite.com";
     }
});
</script>
```

---

Non jQuery option (most use width and it depends on device orientation at times):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width < 1024 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android')!=-1)
(window.location.replace("http://www.yoursite.com"));
</script>
```

---

Another option is use the meta viewport tag and @media queries in your CSS but that won't have the redirect you're looking for.

Comment: I see the no JS and no JQUERY ... either you added or I missed.  Php does not have access to the client system, however, so you'll have to use JS to detect screen resolution.  Php runs SERVER side and not CLIENT side.  You include code above in index.php and change your window.location to tablet.php or phone.php respectively based on your resolution guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but please read carefully. I know that javascript is client side and PHP is server side. Please read again the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: the latency could simply be your server response time or network, but the browser still has to load the DOM.  You might want to simply move your form submit as an inline script at end of body content instead of an onload event.

Comment: what you desire is to perform 2 redirects when 1 will do.  first you detect size and redirect back to same page and PHP logic then calls the header function and redirects to appropriate page.  2 redirects just because you want PHP to handle it instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Ah, i see your PHP code you're doing a conditional include instead based on the size

Comment: Yes, with the same file (index.php) I would like to detect the device, get the screen height, do a conditional include. The third code snippet works actually, but there's that strange latency. Firebug goes mad: it starts flashing and it does not stop.

Comment: did you add condition in the PHP to not include the javascript code if the isset($_POST['height']) ?

Also given you cannot control when onload occurs, move your form.submit in the script tags after where you set the hidden val. I'll edit my answer above

Comment: Please see my edited answer.  I think you may have had a race condition as you were calling the form submit regardless of match for height var.  Also it will redirect faster if you use inline script instead of waiting for full DOM to load with onload event.

Comment: EXCELLENT !! Perfect, elegant, compact. I have no other words... Thank you.

Comment: my pleasure.  I've been a reader of SO for years so figured I'd give back and started an account 2 weeks ago.  I'm a little addicted but a rush solving the problems as you know (why we code).  Good luck with your app.